# How to get a matching word surrounded by hash tags with PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have something similar to this:

```
<a href="#action_link#" target="_blank">Token1</a><br>
<a href="##action_link##" target="_blank">Token1</a><br>
```

And I need to get only the one(s) that is/are surrounded by only one hashtag (#), for this sample I need only the first anchor tag.

I have tried also with grabbing the href attr to filter and make the regexp more easier with something like this:

```
preg_match_all('/<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??|\'??)(#action_link#?)[^>]*>/siU', $someHTML, $match);
```

But with no success :(

Could you please help me?

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
preg_match('/\"\#(.*)\#\"/im', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Where `$string` is your string to search